# What is the current behavior of firefox for the ubuntu menu bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox, applet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to development an applet (https://github.com/lestcape/Global-AppMenu) to be used in the Cinnamon desktop. My intention is not modify or create any other code than not be cjs (*javascript* code). All that i do is:

1. Connect my applet to the *com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar* and the *Gtk
   Dbus API*.
2. Get all *object path* from the *muffin* windows manager (a fork of
   *mutter*).
3. Read and ask things over *Dbus* and then show the result of
   that. I used all patches of Unity desktop, as I'm a user of Ubuntu 14.04.

Nemo, Nautilus, File-Roller, gnome-terminal, VLC, SMPlayer, Evince, are examples of applications that currently are working. At the moment, I only have a problem with one application, and this application is ***Firefox***.

I'm pretty sure that i do something wrong, just i don't have any idea of what could be.

Firefox called the *com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar* service perfectly, i also can trigger the *Alt* key and firefox don't try to show the *menubar* inside the window, but after some time (*a minute*), he emit a *layout change* signal **without** *menu items*, and will show the menubar to the user inside the main window, as is "normally".

My idea is that: this could be, because i'm missing to call some *aboutToShow*, or because firefox require a **confirmation** that i receive the menubar, and he required really that this will be done for the same *GDBus Connection* where he exported the menu bar, but i can not be sure who internally will be handled in that way, as i'm on javascript.

Any way the firefox behavior, apparently is a behavior with an ***know cause***, and what i try to find is the cause of that behavior, to then I will try to find a solution.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and thunderbird require a returned confirmation value from the Dbus connection, as i say in the question. This value is not returned in the default cinnamon code, i force to return the value and now the problem is resolved. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the **about:config** page and search for the "**ui.use_unity_menubar**" entry. As I know, this setting toggle between using unity global menu or normal menu. Maybe this could help you.

Good luck with your applet, I'm waiting for more stable release and then I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, for try to help, but this is not the problem and i suppose that not be any configuration problem. As i say, the menu is loaded and the problem occurs later, when Firefox recovers his menu.